# PHP Mutli-Dimensional Array Grabbing Item

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an API which I'm trying to get an ID from, but the output is a mutli-dimensional array and I can't grab just the ID.

This is what the array looks like:

```
Array ( [{ data] => [ { account_key [ is_owner] => true [ id] => 1 [ name] => test [ display_name] => test [ balance] => 0 [ paid_to_date] => 0 [ updated_at] => 1577724986 [ archived_at] => null [ address1] => [ address2] => [ city] => [ state] => [ postal_code] => [ country_id] => 0 [ work_phone] => [ private_notes] => [ public_notes] => [ last_login] => [ website] => [ industry_id] => 0 [ size_id] => 0 [ is_deleted] => false [ payment_terms] => 30 [ vat_number] => [ id_number] => [ language_id] => 0 [ currency_id] => 0 [ custom_value1] => [ custom_value2] => [ invoice_number_counter] => 1 [ quote_number_counter] => 1 [ task_rate] => 0 [ shipping_address1] => [ shipping_address2] => [ shipping_city] => [ shipping_state] => [ shipping_postal_code] => [ shipping_country_id] => 0 [ show_tasks_in_portal] => true [ send_reminders] => true [ credit_number_counter] => 1 [ custom_messages] => {} [ contacts] => [ { account_key [ is_owner] => true [ id] => 1 [ first_name] => test [ last_name] => test [ email] => me@idontlikespam.com [ contact_key] => mq1dzpkqznfgtqwhdwt9nte1ohmvsju1 [ updated_at] => 1577724986 [ archived_at] => null [ is_primary] => true [ phone] => [ last_login] => [ send_invoice] => true [ custom_value1] => [ custom_value2] => } ] } ] [ meta] => { pagination [ count] => 1 [ per_page] => 15 [ current_page] => 1 [ total_pages] => 1 [ links] => [] } } } )
```

This is the code I have so far to split it out:

```
    $clients = str_replace('"', "", $clients);
$convert_to_array = explode(',', $clients);
for($i=0; $i < count($convert_to_array ); $i++){
$key_value = explode(':', $convert_to_array [$i]);
$end_array[$key_value [0]] = $key_value [1];
}
print_r($end_array);    
foreach ($end_array as $key => $item)
{
    echo "[" . $key . "] => " . $item . "<br />";
    if ($key = ' id')
    {
        echo $item;
    }
}
```

It's just the final step I'm missing, it's probably something easy, but I'm still running on a Christmas brain...

New data:

```
stdClass Object ( [data] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [account_key] => jvg7qgtw2btrlmpigrq2zpco48eegxvv [is_owner] => 1 [id] => 1 [name] => test [display_name] => test [balance] => 0 [paid_to_date] => 0 [updated_at] => 1577724986 [archived_at] => [address1] => [address2] => [city] => [state] => [postal_code] => [country_id] => 0 [work_phone] => [private_notes] => [public_notes] => [last_login] => [website] => [industry_id] => 0 [size_id] => 0 [is_deleted] => [payment_terms] => 30 [vat_number] => [id_number] => [language_id] => 0 [currency_id] => 0 [custom_value1] => [custom_value2] => [invoice_number_counter] => 1 [quote_number_counter] => 1 [task_rate] => 0 [shipping_address1] => [shipping_address2] => [shipping_city] => [shipping_state] => [shipping_postal_code] => [shipping_country_id] => 0 [show_tasks_in_portal] => 1 [send_reminders] => 1 [credit_number_counter] => 1 [custom_messages] => {} [contacts] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [account_key] => jvg7qgtw2btrlmpigrq2zpco48eegxvv [is_owner] => 1 [id] => 1 [first_name] => test [last_name] => test [email] => ema@il.co.uk [contact_key] => mq1dzpkqznfgtqwhdwt9nte1ohmvsju1 [updated_at] => 1577724986 [archived_at] => [is_primary] => 1 [phone] => [last_login] => [send_invoice] => 1 [custom_value1] => [custom_value2] => ) ) ) ) [meta] => stdClass Object ( [pagination] => stdClass Object ( [total] => 1 [count] => 1 [per_page] => 15 [current_page] => 1 [total_pages] => 1 [links] => Array ( ) ) ) )
```

Comment: how $item look like? var_dump($item); die;

Comment: you need use double equal comparsion. One is `SET` and two are `COMPARE` so if ($key == ' id') {..

Comment: Your code to "split it out" looks a lot like you are decoding manually from a JSON format.. Have you tried to replace all what's before the `foreach` by `$end_array = json_decode($clients);`? (that wont solve your main problem but may avoid you other problems - see @daremachine's comment for your main problem)

Comment: refer to what @daremachine said. You need if ($key == 'id'). double == to compare.

Comment: Thank you, have done a json_decode and double == but now when I try and look at $item it gives another array

Comment: please show us your data. What is $item?

Comment: New data above, $item now just gives another copy of the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Array` you can access to values by `[index]`.
In `stdObject` you can access to properties by `->` because it is object.

**So**
stdClass Object ( [data] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [account_key]

**Is**
Object->(property data has value array)[index 0 in array and is object]->(property account_key)

On your data you need this.

```
foreach ($end_array->data as $key => $item)
{
    echo $item->id . "<br />";
}
```

or if you know if data can have always one item you can access with this shortcut

```
echo $end_array->data[0]->id;
```